# Async Middleware on VueJS or a way to catch error in router

Tags: vue.js, authorization, router, middleware

It's my first question on Stack Overflow.

I use VueJS for Frontend and Laravel for Backend. My issue is I have to load a model from my backend API that my user will edit. But there are policies on that model, so my API can response 403 error if the user is not allowed. Perfect !

But how to handle it in VueJS ? Here my router :

```
{ path: '/article/:id(\\d+)/edit', component: page('article/edit/index.vue') }
```

If I make a middleware, I will have the response asynchronously, does it work ? And if the user has access to data, can I pass it to my store ? It doesn't look the cleanest way to do it...

I prefer to do something like that :
On my page component, when I call the API, if the response is 403 I'd like to throw an error. But where can I catch that error in my routes config to auto-redirect with a flash message ?

Is there a better way to do that ?

Thanks !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you using to interact with your Laravel api? Axios?

If you're using axios, I'd recommend researching [Axios interceptors](https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors). They let you capture anything about your request / response **before** it gets back to your Vuex action (or wherever it's being called from). So, when you're setting up your Axios instance, you'd want to do something like the below code snippet:

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import router from '../router';

axios.interceptors.response.use(
    response => {
        return Promise.resolve(response);
    },
    error => {
        const { status, data } = error.response;
        if (status === 404 || status === 403) {
            router.push("/not-found");
        }
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
);
```

What that code is doing is listening for an error from Axios (your backend will make axios error if it gets either a 4xx or 5xx response) and then checking the status code returned from your API, if it detects a 404 (not found) or 403 (forbidden), it will redirect the user to a not-found page. This can of course be customised.

Comment: Thx, I think it’s perfect for me !

Answer (score 0):

i think this is the best way,

1 first you check that the router param is a real number
2 call the api and get the result, if you get some error you show a dialog or something

```
<script>
export default {
    beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
        //check param is a real number
        if (!isNaN(to.params.id)) {
            next();
        }
        else {
            next(false); //or show message error (maybe redirect to a /error)
        }
    },
    mounted(){
        axios
            .get('yoursite.com').then((response) => this.response = response)
            .catch((error) => {
                //show error or redirect to (/error or /logout)
            })
    }
}
</script>
```